# How to export a state in react native, and import it into another file? (NOT COMPONENT)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-props

I am trying to export this state: `const [jsonText, setJSONText] = useState();` out of my file. I tried a simple `export const jsonText;`, but that did not work at all. I tried looking it up, but they were all for components. Is there a way I can do this, and to keep making sure that the constant is still updating even when it's in the other file? I tried passing it as a prop and that did not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State can't be import or export and only can be passed as a [prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) or by using [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

I would advise you to learn about state and react in general.

Here are some resources:

- [Official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)
- [React JS Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8)